# Stop EF Database Initialization for DefaultMembershipProvider

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

Team, I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I'm deploying.  When I deploy it the application works fine, but when I call `Membership.CreateUser` it ends up trying to create the database even though it already exists.  What do I need to do to get it so that it will not try to call `CreateMembershipEntities` since the database already exists?

I've tried `Database.SetInitializer` to an initializer that does nothing, I've tried removing the `defaultConnectionFactory` in the Web.config - I'm currently out of options.

I look forward to your help!

**UPDATE**

I just found out yesterday that the reason it's trying to create the database is because the hosts servers do not allow the connection to query `sysdatabases` and so the database **never** exists and is hence always trying to create it.  It appears that I may have to go back to the old fashioned AspNet membership provider and also go away from the EF code first model.

Comment: "*I've tried Database.SetInitializer to an initializer that does nothing*": The normal way to disable DB initialization is setting the initializer to `null`, i.e. `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null)`. But I have no idea what this EF stuff has to do with the ASP.NET MembershipProvider which uses Stored Procedure and it own connections (unless you have customized the provider somehow). I'd be surprised if setting the initializer to `null` solves the problem.

Comment: @Slauma The issue I'm having is that it's trying to create the membership tables when they already exist on the production database.  I don't have DROP and CREATE database access on the production server.  One other thing worth noting here is that the production server is GoDaddy and the membership provider I'm using is the DefaultMembershipProvider that it configures in a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  It's working great on my development box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a look here: [http://www.qualitydata.com/learn/web-config-membership-provider-settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20120520145119/http://www.qualitydata.com/learn/web-config-membership-provider-settings)
It shows the Membership configuration section of the web.config. You have to write a similar section and put connectionStringName="Your Connection String". In your connection string you specify the informations of the already existing database.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Let me ask you a quick question.  I recently found out - like yesterday afternoon - that the reason I'm having so much trouble is because the hosts servers don't allow the connection string to query `sysdatabases`.  And since I'm using the EF code first approach the default membership provider tries to validate the existence of the database.  Should I just go back to the old fashioned AspNet membership provider?  It's just not as clean.

Comment: The answer to the problem was to use the SqlMembershipProvider instead of the DefaultMembershipProvider.  The SqlMembershipProvider conforms to the membership provider interfaces but works like it used to - it doesn't try to create a database if one doesn't exist.  My advice to everybody is to NOT use the EF code first stuff.